# Snowflake SQL - How do I compare the current row counts of all tables to the row counts from 24 hours ago?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake has time travel, which allows the querying of an object at a specific time stamp. It also has information_schema.tables, which is a view that shows the row counts for all tables as they exist currently. Since this is a view, it obviously can't be used in conjunction with time travel. This is a problem, as I need to compare the current row counts of all individual tables to what they were 24 hours ago.

Since information_schema.tables is a view, by definition it's a query - is there a place to find the script for this, so I can then use time travel in conjunction with it?

Failing that, is there some way to join onto a table using the table name present in the information schema?

Otherwise, is there a different/better way to do this? (taking daily snapshots is unfortunately not an option)

Comment: I'm trying to understand - why would a daily snapshot of the row count not be acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can achieve this with two ways:

1. Materializing the row count from information_schema.tables once a day into a new table (i.e. not materializing all the data from all your tables but just materializing the results of the view or even less just materializing the `select sum(ROW_COUNT) from information_schema.tables;`)
2. Using time travel and run `select count(*) from myTable at(offset => -60*60*24)` for each of your tables to get their individual row counts and then sum them up.

Comment: Unfortunately the snapshot of the count per day is non-starter

As for your second point, the idea was to be able to make this scalable without hardcoding in table names - we've already got >400 tables, and more will likely be added in the future

Comment: Regarding second point: You can also write a Stored Procedure, loop over all your tables from information_schema.tables and then run the query for each of them - then it's flexible and not hardcoded.

Comment: Company limitations on the creation of tables, I'm afraid. And I thought about using loops, even wrote a script that extracted the table names from the information schema and used relative table querying, but unfortunately Snowflake doesn't support loops at all

Comment: It does support loops. Stored Procedures can be written in JavaScript and JavaScript has a looping syntax. Link to Stored Procedures in Snowflake: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures.html